# How to only deform (GKEY in Edit Mode) selected faces?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, selection-tools, shape-keys

I want to only push forward the front faces, but not the side faces, like in the image below

[image]

Comment: It should be the default behavior. Maybe you accidentally activated the PET with the O key. Try pressing O again.

Comment: But I need O to change all faces in proportion, so the behaviour is probably normal (I think). I tried cutting off those faces inbetween the edge that got deformed and the faces inside the green circle but it didn't work either.

Comment: If you're using preportional editing, have you tried making the influence area smaller with the mousewheel? (If it's bigger than the screen, things can be confusing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide (<kbd>H</kbd>) the vertices you don't want to move. They won't be affected by the PET.

To make them appear again, unhide them with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>.